# Is it possible to use only positive covid record for prediction

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, statistics, prediction

I am trying to perform covid-19 data for creating prediction model.

I have very good data for positive patient. Which has these parameters.

```
Fever   Tiredness   Cough   Difficulty-in-Breathing Sore-Throat None_Sympton    Pains   Nasal-Congestion    Runny-Nose  Diarrhea    None_Experiencing   Age_0-9 Age_10-19   Age_20-24   Age_25-59   Age_60+ Gender_Female   Gender_Male Gender_Transgender  Severity_Mild   Severity_Moderate   Severity_None   Severity_Severe Contact_Dont-Know   Contact_No  Contact_Yes Country
```

Problem with me is, I don't find negative patient data with similar parameters.

I have one negative patient data which has only 4500 records and that also missing age, sex, location information

What I want to know is : is it possible that some how we use only positive patient data and try tp predict covid probability?

As per my ML understand, we need balanced data for both class. But I am curious to know if there is any technique to deal with this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that your data has Features strongly corresponding to positive covid patients ,you can do an classification Approach with a classifer with Decision tree where you can Input only Features of the positive Covid patients Features to check the probability of COVID.

You can also use the Naive bayes classification model using the conditional probability with the same Approach.

To check the accuracy of probability you can use classifier metrics like LOG-LOSS to compare it with the true value and predicted proability.

Hope this is helpful